# What axioms do I need to search the naturals?

Tags: coq, axiom-of-choice, markovs-principle

```
Theorem search
  {P : nat -> Prop} (dec : forall n, {P n} + {~P n})
: ~~(exists n, P n) -> {n | P n}.
Admitted.
```

I don't think this is provable in Coq without additional axioms, and it is provable when assuming `LEM : forall A : Prop, A \/ ~A`. However, I don't think it proves LEM. What are the weakest axioms that prove `search`? I'm not very familiar with all the versions of the axiom of choice, but I guess this is probably equivalent to one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an axiom in itself, known as Markov's principle. A more compact but equivalent way to state this axiom is

```
Axiom MP : forall (f : nat -> bool), ~~ (exists n, f n = true) -> exists n, f n = true.
```

The original phrasing of the question hardwires a bit of choice that is provable in CIC, known as constructive definite description.

```
Lemma description : forall (f : nat -> bool), (exists n, f n = true) -> {n | f n = true}.
```

This theorem is [a consequence of singleton elimination](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.ConstructiveEpsilon.html).

Markov principle is not provable in CIC, but it enjoys a special status amongst semi-classical principles. As already observed, it is a consequence of classical logic in Prop. As such it does not endanger the computational properties of extraction. Even better, you can actually natively extend CIC with it without breaking strong normalization and canonicity. See for instance [this other question](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/972/incorporating-markovs-principle-in-various-proof-assistants) for more details.

Comment: Doesn't $P$ need to be decidable for the description lemma?

Comment: Indeed, you need decidability. I'll fix the answer accordingly.

Comment: I believe the `description` axiom given here is, strictly speaking, constructive _indefinite_ description as it does not include uniqueness of `n` as a hypothesis. However this is not really important as the natural numbers are well-ordered and so we can always add the constraint that `n` be minimal among elements satisfying `f`.